Uneven voltage/current density distribution using FEM
I am trying to use the FEM tools in order to generate a current density mask for a trapezoidal racetrack. The voltage input is a 1 unit wide x 2 unit tall pad that I defined in the Laplacian equation. I am starting the simulation like this:
    Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
(*Define the rectangular mesh dimensions*)
xMin = 0; xMax = 40;(*Grid spacing*)
yMin = -5; yMax = 5;
dx = 0.01; dy = 0.01;  
(*Generate grid points for the rectangular mesh*)
gridPoints = 
  Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, xMin, xMax, dx}, {y, yMin, yMax, dy}], 1];

vertices = {{0, -1.25}, {0, 1.25}, {40, 5}, {40, -5}}
region = Polygon[vertices]

pde = -Laplacian[V[x, y], {x, y}] == 
   Piecewise[{{1, 19.5 <= x <= 20.5 && -1 <= y <= 1}}, 0];
bcd = {
    DirichletCondition[V[x, y] == 0, x == 0]
   (*DirichletCondition[V[x,y]==10,x==20]*)
   };

potential =
  NDSolveValue[{pde, bcd}, V, {x, y} \[Element] region, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.05}, 
     "IntegrationOrder" -> 5}];

currentDensity = -Grad[potential[x, y], {x, y}] * CFB_cond;

My thought would be that the distribution should be somewhat even considering the initial conditions of the simulation; however, my problem is that whenever I generate my voltage distribution (and solve for the negative gradient) I notice that the current distribution in the regions outside of the voltage potential are very uneven. I was wondering why this occurs. Is this a problem of mesh size/resolution? I have attached a figure of visualization of the output to demonstrate what I am talking about, as well as some simulation output figures.




The black region is generated from mumax3 and is included to show that the current density in the region of potential gradient is somewhat uniform.

Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory Tour now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

can you clarify for others what mumax3 is ? It is not entirely clear what you are showing in the last image? what is the colour, what does grey show or the black region. this will help others solve your problem

In your code, you don't use the variable gridPoints

As pointed out by the comments and answer below, your question needs further clarification. The question will be reopened once it becomes clear enough.

There is a lot of documentation on making PDE models in electromagnetics. Have a look at the ElectroMagnetics Overview, the Electrostatics and the Electric Currents monograph and the accompanying electromagnetics functions listed on Electromagnetic PDEs and Boundary Conditions guide page.
Those show many examples and present a workflow. Using this here will lead to something like:
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
vertices = {{0, -1.25}, {0, 1.25}, {40, 5}, {40, -5}};
base = Polygon[vertices];
region = RegionDifference[base, Rectangle[{19.5, -1}, {20.5, 1}]];
material = <|"base" -> 1, "whatever" -> 2|>;
mesh = ToElementMesh[region, "RegionHoles" -> None, 
  "RegionMarker" -> {{{1, 0}, material["base"]}, {{20, 0}, 
     material["whatever"], 0.1}}];

mesh["Wireframe"]


pde = -Laplacian[V[x, y], {x, y}] == 
   Piecewise[{{1, ElementMarker == material["whatever"]}}, 0];
bcd = {DirichletCondition[V[x, y] == 0, x == 0]
   (*DirichletCondition[V[x,y]==10,x==20]*)};

potential = NDSolveValue[{pde, bcd}, V, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]

I am not 100% sure you need the next step, that's not clear from your post. Create a discontinuous interpolating function - for the reason please read the appropriate sections on multiple materials
difPotential = DiscontinuousInterpolatingFunction[potential]

And create the plots
Show[
 ContourPlot[difPotential[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  Contours -> 50],
 ToBoundaryMesh[mesh]["Wireframe"], AspectRatio -> Automatic]


(* not sure what CFB_cond is. *)
(*currentDensity=-Grad[potential[x,y],{x,y}]*CFB_cond*)

currentDensity = -Grad[difPotential[x, y], {x, y}]

VectorPlot[currentDensity, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]


